# How to incubate freeze dried culture?

Tags: microbiology, lab-techniques

I have a freeze dried culture of *staphylococcus aureus*; how do I incubate it?

Can I just mix it into Luria broth and just keep it in the incubator?

Comment: Yes, it's that easy!

Comment: Please don't ask the same question repeatedly. You were already given an answer to your previous question, why did you ask again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many micro-organisms do not tolerate freeze drying (you should freeze them using cryo-protectants). Apparently *Staphylococcus* can tolerate it. You don't directly put the dried cells in the medium. First you have to rehydrate the cells using the medium and then transfer them to the culture vessel. See the following instructions from [ATCC](https://www.atcc.org/~/media/rfdc.ashx):

> The preferred method for long-term preservation of bacteria and algae
>   is freeze-drying; however, some bacteria do not survive freeze-drying
>   well and are frozen instead. For freeze dried cultures, using a single
>   tube of the recommended media (5 to 6 mL), withdraw approximately 0.5
>   to 1.0 mL with a Pasteur or 1.0 mL pipette. Use this to rehydrate the
>   entire pellet, and transfer the entire suspension back into the broth
>   tube and mix well. The last few drops of this suspension may also be
>   transferred to an agar slant. Alternatively, algal cultures must be
>   initiated on agar plates. Please note that anaerobic bacterial
>   cultures must be rehydrated in an anaerobic environment; the viability
>   of the cells decrease rapidly if the vial is rehydrated in an oxygenic
>   environment.
>
> Incubate cultures under the appropriate conditions. Given proper
>   treatment and conditions, most freeze-dried cultures will grow out in
>   a few days. However, some may exhibit a prolonged lag period and
>   should be given twice the normal incubation time before discarding as
>   nonviable.

If you had received the cells from some repository or a vendor, you would have also got an instruction manual on how to revive the cells and what media to use. It is best to follow the specific instructions given in the manual.

Comment: What is special about the rehydration medium? Like what is it made of?

Comment: @user2990508 From ATCC manual it appears that is same as the medium in which you are going to grow the cells. If you are buying from a vendor then follow the specific instructions mentioned by them.